# How to get a paragraphs number in a word document with C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I use the assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

My document is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document object, and I want to get the number of each paragraph in this document.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the number of each paragraph"?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315728, its made with VB.net. I want to do the same thing with C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    object docPth = @"c:\tmp\aDoc.doc";
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref docPth, ref misValue, ref misValue,
        ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue,
        ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue);
    wordApp.Visible = true;
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph aPar in aDoc.Paragraphs)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range parRng = aPar.Range;
        string sText = parRng.Text;
        string sList = parRng.ListFormat.ListString;
        int nLevel = parRng.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber;
        MessageBox.Show("Text = " + sText + " - List = " + sList + " - Level " + nLevel.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before start using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library/dll, you must read documentation of that library.

Read here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraphs_members.aspx

Also, depends what version of Office do you use.

Comment: I've already read the documentation, I use visual studio 2008 and the framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Document object, you can already get the 'number' or 'index' of each Paragraph in the document. For example, if you need to get the Text of the second paragraph in the document, you say:

```
MSWord.Application app = (MSWord.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
MSWord.Document doc = app.ActiveDocument; //the document that's on screen and 'active'

Console.WriteLine("Paragraph Count: " + doc.Paragraphs.Count); //show total number of paragraphs available in document.
Console.Write Line("Paragraph number 2 text: " + doc.Paragraphs[2].Range.Text);               //show text of paragraph number 2

Console.ReadLine();
```

If this doesn't help. PLEASE...edit your question. We really cannot do anything with this until you clarify.

Comment: I want to do something similar to that:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315728  But with C# so as to have the list of the paragraph and its level